# gvim often give this error: E8backupdir=~/.vim/tmps failed to start the GUI

Tags: gvim, x11

I often log in remotely to a specific server using ssh -X from a Macbook Pro terminal instance.  When I use gvim then usually I get a local Xwindow and can edit normally while the terminal session remains available for input.  However, this is not always the case.  Often I will run gvim, do some editing, and close the window.  Frequently after I do this when I re-run gvim I get the following messages:

E2backupdir=~/.vim/tmplay
Press ENTER or type command to continue

E8backupdir=~/.vim/tmps failed to start the GUI
Press ENTER or type command to continue

I would like to track down what is causing this and if possible eliminate it.  However, I cannot seem to discover how to debug gvim startup.  Can anyone provide some advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Those errors look like something tried to write error messages and the output of `set backupdir?` at the same time. Try [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604) for some advice tracking down these kinds of problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved by substituting `-Y` for `-X` on the `ssh` client invocation.  There are problems reported with using the `-X` option (treat remote host as untrusted) involving some software applications.  It appears that Vim is one of these.  By using the `-Y` option (treat remote host as trusted) these problems disappear.